# Truffle deployment error while deploying with Infura (Error: Callback was already called)

Tags: truffle, ropsten, truffle-migration, infura, truffle-hdwallet-provider

I am trying to deploy a token smart contract to Ropsten test network with Infura, but I am always getting an error as I am using

> truffle migrate --reset --network ropsten_infura

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.



/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/merkle-patricia-tree/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:358
                callback(err);
^
Error: Callback was already called.
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/merkle-patricia-tree/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:43:1
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/merkle-patricia-tree/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:358:1)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at WriteStream.destroy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/level-ws/level-ws.js:140:1)
    at finish (_stream_writable.js:681:14)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Here are my **truffle-config.js** config file :

```
const path = require("path");
require("dotenv").config({path: "./.env"});
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const AccountIndex = 0;

module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!
  contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "client/src/contracts"),
  networks: {
    development: {
      port: 7545,
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      network_id: 5777
    },
    ganache_local: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC , "http://127.0.0.1:7545", AccountIndex)
      },
      network_id: 5777
    },
    goerli_infura: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC, "https://goerli.infura.io/v3/INFURAKEY", AccountIndex);
      },
      network_id: 5
    },
    ropsten_infura: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC, "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/INFURAKEY", AccountIndex);
      },
      network_id: 3
    } 
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.6.1"
    }
  }
};
```

I am using:

- **truffle** 5.1.23
- **npm** 6.14.4
- **node** 14.0.0
- **truffle-hdwallet-provider** 1.0.34

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Can you share your migrations scripts?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, after asking a around and searching around a bit, here is the quick solution and reason.

My setting is:
Truffle v5.1.31
node v14.4.0
Solidity v0.5.0

1. downgrade the ndoe to 12, which is not I want, so i found way 2
2. run "truffle migrate --network ropsten --skipDryRun"
   (https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/3008)

Because the ganache-cli's internal core is not yet node 14 compatible, so sky dry run as explained by Cruz Molina from the previous issue.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem, it seems to arise with Node 14.
I dont get the error with Node v13